# Why rbenv does not work on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to run a Ruby on Rails project which has the version `2.4.1`and my system is `2.6.x`.
What I did was install via Rbenv the old version of Ruby then I did the following commands:

```
rbenv global 2.4.1 -> to change global Ruby version

ruby -v 
ruby 2.6.5p114

rbenv global
2.4.1
```

So there is something wrong as I would like to use 2.4.1 but seems not working that. I'm unable to start the bundle as it is saying I don't have 2.4.1 installed.

I need a solution to Mac OS Catalina as I did as I found online but nothing works and cannot be started the project.

Comment: Looks like you don't have the rbenv shims in your path, or the entry for the shims is after the entry for `/usr/bin`. What's the output when you run `which ruby` and `echo $PATH`?

Comment: ^^ what's the answer to mikej's comment?

Answer (score 11):

Try `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`. If that solves your problem, add that line to your .bash_profile or ~/.zshrc (Credits to @Agney, see comment below)

Comment: MacOS Catalina uses zsh by default, if you are using the same you want to add the line to `~/.zshrc`

Comment: Excellent addition. I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely Catalina's switch from bash to zsh that's causing the problem:

https://programmingzen.com/installing-rbenv-on-zsh-on-macos/

Thankfully, it's pretty simple to go back to bash:

https://www.howtogeek.com/444596/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-in-macos-catalina/

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a `global` versioning.

Instead, put a file named `.ruby-version` at the root of your Rails project, with a single line content `2.4.1`.

```
echo "2.4.1" > /your/rails/project/.ruby-version
```

It will tell `rbenv` to use this ruby version when current directory is your project directory.

Comment: I did exactly like that when run still say error as there is not the right version of ruby installed