# Jekyll install issues. Jekyll installed using bash terminal but "jekyll: command not found" error output when I try to check the version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I have followed the installation process on the jekyll website and this website: https://desiredpersona.com/install-jekyll-on-macos/

I believe the issue is to do with setting the path variables and perhaps version conflicts.

here is the output from gem env.

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.0.0 (2020-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin20]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/michaelclouting/gems
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/michaelclouting/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/michaelclouting/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/michaelclouting/gems/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/michaelclouting/.local/share/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/michaelclouting/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-darwin-20
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/michaelclouting/gems
     - /Users/michaelclouting/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0
     - /Users/michaelclouting/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/michaelclouting/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec
     - /Users/michaelclouting/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/michaelclouting/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/michaelclouting/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/michaelclouting/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/michaelclouting/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Comment: If you followed that tutorial you should also have Bundler installed. What do you get when you type `bundle --version` in your terminal?

Comment: Bundler version 2.2.3

Comment: I thought it might be your PATH, but if you can find `bundler` you should be able to find `jekyll`. Are they both in the same directory? Try `which bundler` and `which jekyll`. If they are in different directories, you'll need to fix your PATH, if they are in the same, you'll need to wait for someone who better understands MacOS.

Comment: Which jekyll returns no results output in the terminal

Comment: Try running `gem install jekyll` again. If it returns errors, update your question with the output. If it installs, try `jekyll --version` and `which jekyll` again.

Comment: I reinstalled and ran ```$ jekyll --version``` the output was
```-bash: jekyll: command not found```

Comment: When I run ```which ruby``` I get ```/usr/bin/ruby```, i believe this should be set to ```/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby```. Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: I found a couple articles that might be helpful: [Why rbenv does not work on Mac OS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790425/why-rbenv-does-not-work-on-mac-os-catalina) & [rbenv not changing ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version). Both have comments about editing your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshenv to update your PATH.